# When all does comma operator not act as a comma operator?

Tags: c++, comma-operator

If you see this code,

```
class A{
public:
    A(int a):var(a){}
    int var;
};

int f(A obj) {
    return obj.var;
}

int main() {
    //std::cout<<f(23);    // output: 23
    std::cout<<f(23, 23);  // error: too many arguments to function 'int f(A)'
    return 0;
}
```

`f(23, 23)` does not compile because the comma acts as a separator here and not as a comma operator.

Where all does a comma **not** work as a comma operator? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a grammatical point of view, the parameters of a function call form an optional *expression-list* inside parentheses. An *expression-list* consists of one or more *assignment-expression* separated by a comma token. A comma can only signify a comma operator where an *expression* is expected.

The comma operator makes an *expression* out of an *expression*, a `,` and an *assignment-expression*, but an *expression* involving a comma operator is not itself an *assignment-expression* so can't appear in an *expression-list* except where it's a constituent of something that is an *assignment-expression*.

For example, you can surround any *expression* (including one using the comma operator) inside parentheses to from a *primary-expression* which is an *assignment-expression* and hence valid in an *expression-list*.

E.g.

*postfix-expression* where the *expression-list* consists of two *assignment-expression* each of which is an *identifier*.

```
f( a, b );
```

*postfix-expression* where the *expression-list* consists of a single *assignment-expression* which is a *primary-expression* which is a parenthesized *expression* using the comma operator.

```
f( (a, b) );
```

Answer (score 8):

> The use of the comma token as an
>   operator is **distinct from its use in
>   function calls and definitions,
>   variable declarations, enum
>   declarations, and similar constructs,
>   where it acts as a separator.**

[Wikipedia - Comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator)

Comment: What are the “similar constructs”?

Comment: @Philipp: Basically, those constructs in which the grammar explicitly describes the meaning of the comma. The above list skips for instance member and friend declarations, which are very similar to variable declarations. Another example would be a temporary object expression such as `Complex(0,1)` which is similar to a function call.

Answer (score 8):

I did a search over the draft Standard. Basically, in the grammar the `-list` productions are the ones that have commas in them to separate different items. The following results are C++03 specific. In C++0x, *expression-list* directly delegates to *initializer-list* because in C++0x brace lists can occur in function and constructor arguments likewise.

- **expression-list** For *function/constructor arguments* (including functional casts)
- **enumerator-list** The list of items of an *enumeration*
- **init-declarator-list** The different names declared in one *declaration*

  Example:

  ```
  int a, b;
  ```
- **parameter-declaration-list** The *parameter* declaration list (surprise!) of a *function*
- **initializer-list** List similar to expression-list, but can include braced expression lists. Used for *aggregate initialization* (initializing arrays or structs)
- **member-declarator-list** Similar to the init declarator list, but for *member declarations* in classes.

  Example:

  ```
  struct A { int a, b; };
  ```
- **base-specifier-list** List of *base-classes* of a class.
- **mem-initializer-list** List of the *initializers* for *members*

  Example:

  ```
  struct A { A():a(0), b(0) { } int a; int b; };
  ```
- **template-parameter-list** List of *template parameter* declarations.
- **template-argument-list** List of *template arguments* passed to a template.
- **type-id-list** List of types for *exception specifications*

  Example:

  ```
  void f() throw(int, bool) { }
  ```

There is an *identifier-list* for macro parameters too, which i haven't got in that list because it's really part of the preprocessor grammar.

Answer (score 7):

This has to do with the language definition of expressions, which is quite complex.

`f(1, 2)` is a function call expression with two parameters. Contrarily, `f((1, 2))` is a function call expression with one parameter, which is the sub-expression `1, 2`, which will evaluate to 2.

Comment: Because comma is an operator here! The result of rightmost expression is returned. Just for clarification to any reader

Answer (score 1):

A comma operator always acts as a comma operator, but a comma doesn't always signify a comma operator -- sometimes it's just punctuation.

As to when it's punctuation, the simple answer is "when the standard says so." Going through all the situations where the standard says so gives a much longer answer -- but one that's unlikely to be much more useful, because (for one example) it has to deal with a number of corner cases most people don't care much about.