# Is this a valid assignment in C++?

Tags: c++

While I was looking at the library code, I found the below line

```
int number = config.nodes,i,fanout=numP/2;
```

I assume config is a pointer to something, but can there be commas in the statement? and make assignment like that?

Comment: See @Als's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6502819/comma-operator-and-comma-seperator-in-c

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This declares three variables.  It's the same as:

```
int number = config.nodes
int i;
int fanout = numP/2;
```

Please note that commas are handled specially in declarations (and argument lists), C++ also has a "comma operator" which is not being used here.

Comment: It's also easy to confuse with the comma operator, so I wouldn't recommend doing it. I, personally, only do an initial assignment with the last declaration of a statement.

Comment: @bdonlan: Funny how I had an idea that mentioning the comma operator (by way of contrast) might be helpful.

Comment: I, personally, only do a single declaration in each statement. Saves people coming here and ask "WTF?". :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's valid, number is not being assigned the entire line you see though.

`i` and `fanout` are 2 other integers also being created at that time, `fanout` is also being initialized at this time.

That one line is equivalent to:

```
int number = config.nodes;
int i;
int fanout = numP/2;
```

Comment: damn... I was 56 seconds late to answer this. ha ha

Answer (score 1):

Its basically many declaration:

```
    int number = config.nodes;
    int i;
    int fanout=numP/2;
```

Answer (score 0):

A more recognizable way to write this would be:

```
int number, i, fanout;
number = config.nodes;
fanout = numP/2;
```

I personally would never write something like your example because it takes too long for the reader to work out what's going on.

Comment: For plain `int` it doesn't matter much, but your variation uses assignment instead of initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following additions:

1) The whitespace is always ignored by the C++ compiler.  So,

```
int number  =   config.nodes,i,fanout=numP/2;
```

is equivalent to

```
// declaring three variables number, i and fanout
int number=config.nodes, i, fanout = numP/2;
```

The comma here is to tell the compiler that i have more than one variable to declare. So, number will be initialized with config.nodes.   If config is a pointer (as you mentioned above), then you cannot access member variables using `.` operator. You have to use `->` instead of `.`.

2) The following line has different semantic:

```
// only one variable will be declared, which is number
int number  =  (config.nodes,i,fanout=numP/2);
```

Inside the parenthesis is an expression and the comma here is a **comma operator**. In this case, `config`, `i`, `fanout` and `numP` are previously defined. The value of comma operator is the value of last expression `fanout=numP/2`.