# Why is comma operator called inside operator [] but not inside operator ()?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, language-lawyer, comma-operator

From this former question [When all does comma operator not act as a comma operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128346), I understood that commas inside a function call can only act as expression sperator. But from the code below, it appears that `operator()` behaves like a function call while `operator[]` does not.

So I have two questions :

1. Why is the comma operator called inside an `operator[]` call and not inside an `operator()` call ?
2. Is there a specific reason that prevents the compiler, first checking that `f(a,b)` does not match both the arity or the types of any f declaration, would not try to change the comma status and see if `f(a.operator,(b))` leads to an acceptable synthax ? From my point of view, it would be the same kind of process that comes with types conversion.

Code example :

```
struct A{ };

struct B {
  A operator,(const B & other) const { return A(); }
};

struct C {
  C(){}
  C(const A & a){}
  void operator[](const A & a) const {}
  void operator()(const A & a) const {}
};

void f(const A & a){}

int main()
{
    B x,y;
    C z;

    //these do no compile because ',' in a function call is an argument separator
    //C(x,y);
    //f(x,y);

    //but this one compiles as z[x.operator,(y)]
    z[x,y];

    //and this one does not
    //z(x,y);

    //finally all of these do compile
    z((x,y));
    C((x,y));
    f((x,y));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look where "expressions" can be used in the syntax.  A parameter pack in not an expression.  A array index is an expression.  The comma operator can only be used in expressions.  Putting round brackets around stuff can in some cases turn them into expressions.  For a full answer add the language-lawyer tag and/or read the standard.

Comment: Well the `operator()` is called the ["*function call* operator"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Function_call_operator) as it is used (and *parsed*) as that.

Comment: That would not make the code more readable, don't you think?

Comment: It would be incredibly confusing if the existence of an `operator,` could decide whether `z(x,y)` had one or two arguments.

Comment: @molbdnilo: that would be an understatement. You wouldn't even know _which_ `f` to consider in the presence of overloads. And what to think about `f(x,y,z)` when `f` takes two parameters - do you try both `f(x,(y,z))` and `f((x,y),z)` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten : Thank you for the tag suggestion. I did not expect the overloaded operator[] to keep the same array index semantic and so to require an expression.

Comment: @molbdnilo I agree it would be confusing, I am just asking out of curiosity. But for example my ide is highlighting custom operators so z(a,b) with one or two arguments would be visually different.

Comment: @MSalters : So the answer is that it would lead to combinatorial explosion in the general case, and such not feasible ?

Comment: @yultan concider the function call: `f(a, b, c, d, e ,f);` which is the comma-operator and which is the parameter-list-separator?  Too hard for the compiler and to be backwards compatible they are all  parameter-list-separator(s).  Knowing that now concider: `g((a, b), (c), (d, e, f));`  You should see that `f` takes 6 parameters and `g` takes only 3.  With the extra commas (inside the extra brackets) in `g` being operators (the brackets around `c` are optional).

Comment: @yultan A language must be understandable without concern for your preferred IDEs text-rendering habits.

Comment: @yultan. Correct. Even the simplest overload pair `f(int)` and `f(int,int)` would need special rules to prevent `f(1,2)` form being ambiguous.

Comment: Note that since C++23 `operator[]` will have same properties as function since multidimensional subscript has been introduced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is the comma operator called inside an `operator[]` call and not inside an `operator()` call?

If you look [grammatically](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#post-1), function calls are of the form *postfix-expression* `(` *expression-list*<sub>opt</sub> `)`. An *expression-list* (which is an [*initializer-list*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.post#nt:expression-list), not to be confused with `std::initializer_list`) is a [comma separated list of *initializer-clause*s](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:initializer-list) (assuming there are at least two clauses). The commas are consumed by the parsing of the *expression-list*, where it has special meaning, rather than an part of an expression.

Indexing is of the form  *postfix-expression* `[` *expr-or-braced-init-list* `]`, there is no comma to be consumed at this point, so any comma that appears is necessarily part of the [*expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#nt:expression).

> Is there a specific reason that prevents the compiler, first checking that `f(a,b)` does not match both the arity or the types of any `f` declaration, would not try to change the comma status and see if `f(a.operator,(b))` leads to an acceptable syntax ?

I'm going to go with "sanity." Function calls are a really fundamental aspect of programs and they need to be straightforward. It would be insanely error-prone if you couldn't even know *how many arguments* you were passing. Especially if the builtin comma operator is used, which simply ignores arguments.

Moreover, it's very simple to force the use of a comma: [add parentheses](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.comma#2):

> ```
> f(a, (t=3, t+2), c);
> ```
>
> has three arguments, the second of which has value `5`.

This works grammatically because the interior comma can't be a comma separating *initializer-clause*s, since `(t=3` is not an *initializer-clause*.

Comment: Besides the general insanity of the idea, you don't know which `f`s you are looking at until you know the arguments (because of ADL), and if you don't know what the arguments are until you know which `f`s exist...

Answer (score 0):

The question and answer explain the behavior of commas in `[]` subscripts correctly for the time they were written.

However, for readers in the present and future:

With C++20 the use of `,` directly in `[]` was deprecated. It should now be parenthesized, meaning that instead of `z[x,y]` one should use `z[(x,y)]`. The comma is still interpreted as `operator,` (or the built-in comma operator) in either case though.

With C++23 the meaning of the comma in `z[x,y]` (without parentheses) will change. It will now be interpreted as `operator[](x,y)`, not `operator[](operator,(x,y))`, just as `z(x,y)` has always been interpreted as `operator()(x,y)`. Previously `operator[]` could only have one argument. With C++23 it will be allowed to have multiple arguments behaving the same way as `operator()`.

This is a breaking change in the language, although use of the comma operator in a `[]` subscript had almost no practical uses and probably surprising/unintended behavior given the difference to `()` and the seemingly multi-dimensional indexing nature of the syntax.